# FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON does not work during keygaurd lock

Tags: android

Hi I am an Android newbie, I want to create an app which stays displayed even if the power button is pressed, I used,

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
```

but I had to press power button again to display the app, someone suggested me to use,

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Is there any work around ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't prevent hardware keys overriding. Power button works on hardware level. Ur app will be unable to turn screen on after it was turned off by hardware.